# How to find control in formview item template

Tags: c#, asp.net

*I have tried this -*

```
if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
{
 DropDownList ddlexpense = (DropDownList)FormView1.Row.FindControl("ddle");
}
```

on  FormView1 DataBound ,Init,ItemCreated and a seperate Function ,but i always get the same error - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

```
var cnt = FindControl(formViewTemplate.Row, "controlName");
            var htmlControl = cnt as HtmlControl;
            if (htmlControl != null)
            {//---------------------}
private Control FindControl(Control parent, string id)
    {
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            string childId = string.Empty;
            if (child.ID != null)
            {
                childId = child.ID;
            }
            if (childId.ToLower() == id.ToLower())
            {
                return child;
            }
            if (child.HasControls())
            {
                Control response = FindControl(child, id);
                if (response != null)
                    return response;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```